# Django Validators : check if two fields values have the same id in the database

Tags: django, forms, validation

I'm new to Django, and i have a form that has two fields :
Client name & bill number .
i've created a validator that tests if the bill number already exists in the database table (called bills).
But now i need to transform this validator to another that tests in addition of the previous test,  if the Client name exists in the same table line (more smiply : if client name and the bille number have the same pk).
The validator :

```
def validate_url(value):
    try:
        entry=facture_ventes.objects.get(numfac=value)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        entry = None
    if entry is not None:
        factexist=facture_ventes.objects.all().filter(id=entry.id).count()
        if factexist  is not None:
            raise ValidationError("Numéro de Facture déja saisi ! ")
```

the form :

```
class SubmitUrlForm(forms.Form):
    numfacture=forms.CharField(label='Submit Form', validators=[validate_url])
```

here is the data base table :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xmpd.png

any help please, cause i know that validators cant return a value so i'm stuck here. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a job for a validator, but for the form's `clean` method.

```
def clean(self):
    numfac = self.cleaned_data.get('numfacture')
    try:
        entry=facture_ventes.objects.get(numfac=numfac)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        entry = None
    if entry is not None:
        factexist=facture_ventes.objects.all().filter(id=entry.id).count()
        if factexist is not None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Numéro de Facture déja saisi ! ")
        if entry.client_name == self.cleaned_data.get('client_name'): # or whatever
            raise forms.ValidationError("Facture avec ce numéro et cliente existe déjà")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. okey i see, i will test it . i guess the clean method should be on my views file ? is that right ?

Comment: No, it's a method on the form.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH YOU HELPED ME A LOT

Comment: i have a question Please, what if i transform the second field to a ModelChoiceField would there be any modifications ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try using get_or_create() method:

obj, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(first_name='Angus', last_name='Young')
This could return:

- If it exist:

`obj`: The object from your DB

`created`: False

- If it doesn't exist:

`obj`: The new created object

`created`: True